# NHibernate does not filter data base on COORECT TYPE of meta data

Tags: nhibernate, c#-4.0, fluent-nhibernate

I have an interface (IContactable) which is realizing by 3 classes : Person, Department, RestUnit

```
public interface IContactable
{
  Contact Contact { get; set; }
  string Title { get; }
  int? Id { get; set; }
}


public class Person:IContactable
public class Department:IContactable
public class RestUnit:IContactable
```

There is another class, Contact, which should maintain which one of these objects are the owner of the contact entity.
A part of Contact mapping which does the job is:

```
    ReferencesAny(p => p.Contactable)
     .EntityTypeColumn("ContactableType")
     .EntityIdentifierColumn("ContactableId")
     .IdentityType<int>()
     .AddMetaValue<Person>("Person")
     .AddMetaValue<Department>("Department")
     .AddMetaValue<RestUnit>("RestUnit");
```

So that Contact records in database would be like (The types are being saved as string):

```
X     Y       ContactableType     ContactableId
...  ...        Person              123
...  ...        Person              124 
...  ...        Department          59879   
...  ...        RestUnit              65    
...  ...        Person              3333    
...  ...        Department          35564
```

Everything works just fine but **filtering** data.    When I want to get some particular Contacts, say with Department type, I would write something like :

```
var contacts = Repository<Contact>.Find(p=>p is Department);
```

Nhibernate tries to filter data based on **ContactableType** field with an integer value but the ContactableType column is nvarchar

Generated query by NHibernate :

```
select .......... from contact.[Contact]  where ContactableType=1
```

**Expected query:**

```
select .......... from contact.[Contact]  where ContactableType='Department'
```

So NHibernate kinda using a wrong type. int instead of string.
I think NH is using the index of the object in list which **AddMetaValue("Department")** has added department type into...

I hope the explanation would be clear enough
I'm using NH3....

any idea?

Comment: Nope, unfortunately couldn't find anyway to solve it

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add an extra line:

```cs
ReferencesAny(p => p.Contactable)
    .MetaType<string>()
```